# iPython Notebook Unresponsive Over Long SQL Queries

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I normally am able to run long queries using pyscopg2+sql magic in a Notebook, but lately my Notebooks seems to lose their connection and stall. When I look at my redshift logs, I can see that the queries completed successfully, but my Notebook never gets any data back and just keeps waiting.

What might be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this connection options to my connection string seems to have fixed my problem: keepalives=1&keepalives_idle=60

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for connecting to redshift is with the help of this extension - https://github.com/sat28/jupyter-redshift

The sample notebook shows how it loads redshift utility as an IPython Magic.